# How does one connect to a digital-ocean server from a local React project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, digital-ocean

**Background**

I am working on the front-end of a project using React. The backend is saved on digital ocean, something for which I am a complete novice at, however I have made attempts to read as much as possible. I would like to be able to connect and make calls to the server from my local React project while I'm developing and testing. All that I have been given is the login details to the digital ocean droplet. My problem is that I am not sure what url/endpoint to use to make these calls.

**What I've Tried:**

- Making calls to the ip that was given to me for accessing the droplet. e.g.: `"http://148.41.158.149:8080"` - this is not the official ip, just an example. I found out that this is wrong.
- Using `root@projectname:~# nslookup localhost`, I used the ip given which didn't work.
- I did manage to download the backend from the server and I can make calls to `"http://localhost:8080"`, however I would like to know how to make calls to the server.

From what I understand, I need to retrieve the url for the server from the actual account. Is there any way to get this from the droplet?

Comment: Is the server "public" accessible? You can forward your requests over ssh if not. Otherwise use your public ip/port the application is running on. It should not be that hard

Comment: Hi, @Marc. Thanks for your reply. I don't know why I'm finding it difficult. How can I see if the server is publicly accessible? I don't think it is, but how can I confirm?

Comment: I have no experience with digital-ocean. Sorry, i cant answer that question. But do you hae a SSH access to the server?

Comment: I do have have an SSH and can access the server. I've been looking around for an internet socket to make my calls to.